# UserWarning: No training configuration found in save file: the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After a training procedure, I wanted to check the accuracy by loading the created `model.h5` and executing an evaluation procedure. However, I am getting a following warning:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py:269:
>   UserWarning: No training configuration found in save file: the model
>   was *not* compiled. Compile it manually.   warnings.warn('No training
>   configuration found in save file:

[image]

This `dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py` file

so the problem in loading created model -> this line of code

```
train_model = load_model('model.h5')
```

Problem indicates that the model was not compiled, however, I did it.

```
optimizer = Adam(lr=lr, clipnorm=0.001)
train_model.compile(loss=dummy_loss, optimizer=optimizer)
```

I can't understand what I am doing wrong . . .
Please help me! SOS :-(

Comment: The warning doesn't prevent you from evaluating the model.

Comment: I have the same problem (used `model.save(..., include_optimizer=True)`) (tensorflow's keras implementation)

Answer (score 86):

### Intro

I'd like to add to olejorgenb's answer - for a specific scenario, where you don't want to train the model, just use it (e.g. in production).

"Compile" means "prepare for training", which includes mainly setting up the optimizer. It could also have been saved before, and then you can continue the "same" training after loading the saved model.

### The fix

But, what about the scenario - I want to just run the model? Well, use the `compile=False` argument to `load_model` like that:

```
trained_model = load_model('model.h5', compile=False)
```

You won't be able to `.fit()` this model without using `trained_model.compile(...)` first, but most importantly - the warning will go away.

### Misc Notes

Btw, in my Keras version, the argument `include_optimizer` has a default of `True`. This should work also for trainig callbacks like `Checkpoint`. This means, when loading a model saved by Keras, you can usually count on the optimizer being included (except for the situation: see Hull Gasper's answer).

But, when you have a model which was not trained by Keras (e.g. when converting a model trained by Darknet), the model is saved un-compiled. This produces the warning, and you can get rid of it in the way described above.

Comment: `compile=False` is not working for me. I have lots of models that were saved during the training. I need to load them just to make some inferences and evaluate the different model versions, ant the warning is thrown with both versions. I'm running `Keras==2.2.4`, `tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0`and `python 3.6.6`

Comment: Beautiful solution! Thanks!  Worked swimmingly for me :)

Answer (score 4):

Do you get this warning when saving the model?

```
WARNING:tensorflow:TensorFlow optimizers do not make it possible to access 
optimizer attributes or optimizer state after instantiation. As a result, we 
cannot save the optimizer as part of the model save file.You will have to 
compile your model again after loading it. Prefer using a Keras optimizer 
instead (see keras.io/optimizers).
```

Seems tensorflow optimizers can't be preserved by keras :/

Comment: Do you know if this is still the case in 2019?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned keras can't save Tensorflow optimizers. Use the keras one:

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(...)
model.save('...')
```

This way works for me without manual compiling after calling load.